# SQL Server : database connection with textbox values

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm trying to make a application that connect to a SQL Server database with connection values from textbox but when I try connect it gives me connection error

> error code: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL server

Here is the source of the application:

```
private void ConnectToSQL() {
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + "Initial Catalog=" + textBox1.Text +"User ID=" + textBox2.Text + "Password=" + textBox3.Text;
using (SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        objSqlConnection.Open();
        objSqlConnection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection is successfull");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
```

Please help me with this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: give break point and check the value of connectionstring and paste it here..

Comment: Verify your conntectionstring [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: Check out [the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) instead of concatenating together your connectino string from textbox input...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed a `semicolon(;)` in your connection string. If you append it in your connection string, it should work.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + 
                           ";Initial Catalog=" + textBox1.Text +
                           ";User ID=" + textBox2.Text + 
                           ";Password=" + textBox3.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this .

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to you are missing semi columns in your connection string.

**Try it as:**

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + ";Initial
Catalog=" + textBox1.Text +";User ID=" + textBox2.Text + ";Password="
+ textBox3.Text;
```